# How can I use both required and simple argument in same constructor in flutter 3?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  ReusableCard({required this.colour, this.cardChild});

  final Color colour;
  Widget cardChild;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: cardChild,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0xFF1D1E33),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Put it outside of the `{}`: `ReusableCard(this.cardChild, {required this.colour});`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want it required you need to make it nullable by adding a `?` to the type of the variable. So change

```
Widget cardChild;
```

to

```
Widget? cardChild;
```